# php+mysqlupdate

Tags: php, mysql

I am executing the follwing statements in php,mysql. The database isn't gettig updated.  I dont get any exception or any error notice. The query runs fine but database values are not updated.

```
 $stmt=$dbh->prepare("update stops set lat = ?, lon = ?, issuffolk = ? where id = ?");
 $stmt->execute(array($latitude,$longitude,$issuffolk,$stopId));
```

could anyone let me know what the problem is.

Comment: Execute the above sql query in phpmyadmin and check your results. If query is working fine there, then there is something wrong in the code.

Comment: Did you try to run the same query in MySql console? What happens? Are you sure that query runs fine?

Comment: The query works fine in phpmyadmin and mysql console too

Comment: So you're passing wrong params to query. Are you sure `$latitute` is a float? What is `$issuffolk`?

Comment: Did you try to print on screen your query before execuing it?

Comment: Thanks marco and samir. I was passing a wrong parameter. I checked it after printing the query string and my transaction commit statement was misplaced

Comment: @samir running *this* query in phpmyadmin will make no sense. Go figure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are in a transaction(via `PDO::beginTransaction()` somewhere?), so add `$dbh->commit();` after you executed the prepared statement and check the result.

Comment: +1 Definitely could be in a transaction, especially since prior questions use transactions.